# Does ROS support Lego EV3 now?

Tags: ros, lego

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS diamondback version on ubuntu 10.04 for Lego nxt.
But when I run the sample test program "rosrun nxt_python touch_sensor_test.py "
I got the same output as the webpage shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/u/mwise/external_repos/foote-ros-pkg/nxt/trunk/nxt_python/sensor_tests/touch_sensor_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    sock = nxt.locator.find_one_brick()
  File "/u/mwise/external_repos/foote-ros-pkg/nxt/trunk/nxt_python/src/nxt/locator.py", line 57, in find_one_brick
    raise BrickNotFoundError
nxt.locator.BrickNotFoundError
```

What's the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189653/does-ros-support-lego-ev3-now?/) by [annie029](https://answers.ros.org/users/19990/annie029/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Putting aside the fact that the title and the content of your question don't seem to align,

maybe the duplicate of [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/37109/nxt-bricknotfounderror/). See the answer there and make sure the hardware is recognized on your machine.

Besides that, both ROS Diamondback and Ubuntu 10.04 is obsolete. You better consider using newer distro (Hydro, Indigo for ROS, Precise or Trusty for Ubuntu).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1